# Google analytics custom dimensions for session

Tags: php, session, google-analytics, dimension

I am trying to get more detailed session info but i am unsure how to do that. I want to see the source of the sessions. Determining how many from refferal, direct, social and email. This is how I am querying and printing the results from the api currently

```
// Query the API
function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
    // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries the specified data 
    return $analytics->data_ga->get(
            'ga:' . $profileId,
            '30daysAgo',
            'today',
            'ga:Sessions,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:bounceRate,ga:pageviews,ga:percentNewSessions,ga:pageviewsPerSession');
}




function printResults(&$results) {
  // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
  // the profile name and total sessions.
  if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

    // Get the profile name.
    $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

    // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
    $rows = $results->getRows();
    $visits = $rows[0][0];
    $avgVisitDuration = $rows[0][1];
    $bounceRate = $rows[0][2];
    $pageView = $rows[0][3]; 
    $percentNewSession = $rows[0][4];
    $pagesPerVisit = $rows[0][5]; 
    // Print the results.
echo '
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Total Visits</td>
    <td>',$visits,'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Average Visit Duration</td>
    <td>', floor($avgVisitDuration/ 60),' minutes ',$avgVisitDuration % 60,' seconds </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bounce Rate</td>
    <td>',$bounceRate,' %</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Page Views</td>
    <td>',$pageView,'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Percentage New Visits</td>
    <td>',$percentNewSession,' %</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pages / Visit</td>
    <td>',$pagesPerVisit,'</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>';


  } else {
    print "No results found.\n";
  }
}


$analytics = getService();
$profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
$results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
printResults($results);
```

update: using this dimension i get the error syntax error, unexpected ''); ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' on getResults on the line with 'ga' . profileid
this is how i am trying to query the api

```
$optParams = array(
          'dimensions' => 'ga:medium'
          ');  
function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
    // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries the specified data

    return $analytics->data_ga->get(
            'ga:' . $profileId,
            '30daysAgo',
            'today',
            $optParams,
            'ga:sessions');
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate. What exactly are you trying to do, and what are the errors you are seeing? What methods did you use to troubleshoot so far?

Comment: As i said I want detailed session information, where the sessions originated from as in referral, direct, social and email. Using dimensions like this and adding optParams to the query yields no results                                                               $optParams = array(
          'dimensions' => 'ga:sessionCount'
          ');

Comment: ga:medium would give you social,email,referral etc, ga:source would give you the specific, ehm, source (so for  a visit originating from stackoverflow you'd get medium "social" and source "stackoverflow". See tne field reference https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Comment: I added the code trying to use the dimension medium but I get the error listed above